# Qual a origem da expressão "Tirar o cavalo da chuva"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica

Sei que no português utilizamos isso quase que como uma gíria, e que seu significado é no sentido de que alguma coisa não vai acontecer.

Exemplo:

> Se está pensando que eu vou arrumar o seu quarto, pode tirar o
>   cavalinho da chuva!"

Isso da um sentido de negação, algo muito difícil de acontecer. Mas quando essa expressão começou? Porque? O cavalo gosta tanto assim de tomar chuva que é difícil tirar ele debaixo dela?

Comment: A ideia que eu tenho, mas para já sem nada para a fundamentar é a seguinte. Imagina que noutros tempos vais a cavalo tratar dum assunto, e está a chover. Se o assunto for muito demorado, procuras um abrigo para o cavalo não ficar à chuva; se for rápido, deixa-lo onde for mais conveniente, mesmo que à chuva. Seria como hoje com o carro, que se deixa mal estacionado, se for por pouco tempo. Então *podes tirar o cavalinho da chuva*, seria como hoje dizer, *podes esperar sentado* (não sei se dizem isso no Brasil).

Comment: Nesse caso seria o uso correto então somente quando for chover?

Comment: O uso atual é figurado: não interessa se vai ou não chover.

Comment: Significava que não poderia ir embora ou fazer outra coisa enquanto não realizasse a tarefa, por isso o cavalo teria de ser posto pra dentro do abrigo. Tem-se a ideia de obrigações a cumprir. Adaptou-se o uso.

Comment: @Jacinto - Sim, no Brasil a gente diz, *pode esperar sentado*. Às vezes, para maior ênfase, *pode esperar sentado, que de pé cansa*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom, estava pesquisando sobre o significado e encontrei algo, porém não sei se está correto:

> Por volta do século 19 o cavalo era o meio de transporte mais prático
>   e comum. Era um meio que apresentava muitas vantagens, e uma delas era
>   saber quanto tempo uma visita pretendia ficar em sua casa. Quando o
>   visitante em questão chegava e amarrava o cavalo na frente da casa,
>   isso significava que a visita seria breve. No entanto, se levasse o
>   cavalo para algum local mais resguardado da chuva e do sol, isso
>   significava que a visita com certeza demoraria.
>
> Naquela época, guardar o cavalo (no estábulo, por exemplo) sem a
>   autorização do dono da casa era uma falta de educação muito grave, e
>   por isso normalmente as visitas deixavam o cavalo na parte da frente
>   da casa. Em algumas ocasiões, quando o anfitrião estava contente com a
>   presença do seu visitante e queria que este ficasse durante mais algum
>   tempo, ele lhe dizia para "tirar o cavalo da chuva" e colocá-lo num
>   lugar mais protegido. Ao dizer isso, o dono da casa estava dizendo ao
>   seu convidado para desistir da ideia de ir embora rápido.

Engraçado que seguindo esse pensamento, essa expressão era usada em um sentido positivo, mas hoje não mais.

Fonte: [Significados](https://www.significados.com.br/tirar-o-cavalinho-da-chuva/)